# How can I teach a model using single class in machine learning using Keras?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I am new to machine learning and currently got a good start in binary and multi-class model development using Keras. 
Now I would like to learn how I could teach a model for outlier image detection. 
I used the binary classification method to teach the outlier class by separating the outlier class from other image class. This method does not work as soon as I give an image that was not during teaching and the outcome is totally unpredictable.

1. Where should I start this ?
2. Is there any online tutorial(s) I could follow ?

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, especially [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

There isn't such a thing as single-class classification. Your problem is binary since you are differentiating between two classes (normal, outlier).

Having said that, your problem might be too little data for the outliers. Unbalanced classes might not produce good results so you should try that first. The second problem might be the model's parameters not having the right values, this requires some experimentation on your part.

I can't say much since the problem is so vague. If you want to post some code and some results I could tell more.

Comment: Thank you for your information.  If I have a set of images (example: lions) as my only class that I need to check with the rest of the world images. Suppose I don't have access to other images (binary class), how can I use only available set of images to identify lions ? (Another question : If I train lions with some other random images without lions, will it helpfull to identify lions from any other image ?) When I say any other, those images may be completely differnt to what I used during training (non lion images)

Comment: You are a bit confused about some basics. You can only do classification on two or more classes. A classifier model differentiates between those classes. Else said you need another class that represents "not lion", where you have random images for example. Depending on your problem, you might want to include images of other big cats in the "not lion" class. This would cause the network to focus on the features that makes a lion and not a big cat.